# Last column does not have the desired width

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, columns, width

I am trying to create a table using `tabularx` package. I want the first column to have a certain width (38 mm) and all other columns to have the another width (15 mm). But the last column seems to have a fixed value width, as figure 1 illustrates, no matter the value I set for it.

[image: Figure illustrating what is happening]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}  
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}    

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

    % Definning column specifications:
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\normalsize}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{A}{>{\normalsize\centering\arraybackslash}m{38mm}}
    \newcolumntype{B}{>{\normalsize\centering\arraybackslash}m{15mm}}

    \begin{table}[!hbt]
        \centering
        \caption{Shape functions for quadrilateral elements.} \label{tab.:2DQuadShapeFunc}~\\[-3mm]
        %\begin{tabular}{lc*{4}c}    
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ABBBBB}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Included only if node $i$ is defined} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=5$}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=6$}   
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=7$}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=8$} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=9$}             \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_1=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1-s)$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_5$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_8$}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{4}h_9$}   \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_2=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1-s)$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_5$}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_6$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{4}h_9$}   \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_3=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1+s)$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_6$}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_7$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{4}h_9$} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_4=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1+s)$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_7$} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_8$}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{4}h_9$}   \\ \cline{1-1}
            $h_5=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1-s)$                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_9$} \\ \cline{1-2}
            $h_6=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1+r)$                    &                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_9$}   \\ \cline{1-3}
            $h_7=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1+s)$                    &                                        &                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_9$}   \\ \cline{1-4}
            $h_8=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1-r)$                    &                                        &                   &                            
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_9$}   \\ \cline{1-5}
            $h_9=(1-r^2)(1-s^2)$                             &                                        &                   &                            
            &                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `tabularx`! You overwrite the last column specification with `c` for every line, the reason why it doesn't use the `m{1.5cm}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}  
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\begin{document}    

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

    \newcolumntype{A}{>{\Centering}m{38mm}}
    \newcolumntype{B}{>{\Centering}m{15mm}}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\centering
\caption{Shape functions for quadrilateral elements.}\label{tab.:2DQuadShapeFunc}~\\[-3mm]
        %\begin{tabular}{lc*{4}c}    
\begin{tabular}{A*5B | }
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Included only if node $i$ is defined} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=5$}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=6$}   
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=7$}             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$i=8$} 
    & $i=9$             \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_1=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1-s)$} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_5$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_8$}   &
    $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_2=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1-s)$} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_5$}   &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_6$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$   \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_3=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1+s)$} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_6$}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_7$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            &  $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$ \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$h_4=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1+s)$} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_7$} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-\frac{1}{2}h_8$}   &
            $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$   \\ \cline{1-1}
            $h_5=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1-s)$                    & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}        
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$ \\ \cline{1-2}
            $h_6=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1+r)$                    
            &                                        & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$   \\ \cline{1-3}
            $h_7=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1+s)$                    
            &                                        &                   & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &
            $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$   \\ \cline{1-4}
$h_8=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1-r)$ & & & &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &    $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$   \\ 
\cline{1-5}
            $h_9=(1-r^2)(1-s^2)$                             
            &                                        &                   
            &                            
            &                                        & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

\end{document}
```

[image]

It maybe easier to define the vertical lines and then use `\multicolumn` where it should not appear! Here I show it for the first seven lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}  
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\begin{document}    

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

\newcolumntype{A}{m{38mm}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\Centering}m{15mm}}
\let\MC\multicolumn

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\centering
\caption{Shape functions for quadrilateral elements.}\label{tab.:2DQuadShapeFunc}~\\[-3mm]
        %\begin{tabular}{lc*{4}c}    
\begin{tabular}{A | *5{B|} }
\MC{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Included only if node $i$ is defined} \\
    & $i=5$ & $i=6$ & $i=7$ & $i=8$ & $i=9$ \\ \hline
$h_1=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1-s)$ & $-\frac{1}{2}h_5$ & & & $-\frac{1}{2}h_8$ & 
    $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$ \\
$h_2=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1-s)$ & $-\frac{1}{2}h_5$ & $-\frac{1}{2}h_6$ & & & 
    $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$   \\
$h_3=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1+s)$ & & $-\frac{1}{2}h_6$ & $-\frac{1}{2}h_7$ & &   
    $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$ \\
$h_4=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1+s)$ & & & $-\frac{1}{2}h_7$ & $-\frac{1}{2}h_8$ &
    $-\frac{1}{4}h_9$   \\ \cline{1-1}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_5=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1-s)$} & & & & & $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$ \\ \cline{1-2}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_6=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1+r)$} & \MC{1}{c}{} & & & & $-\frac{1}{2}h_9$   \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_7=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1+s)$} & \MC{1}{c}{}& \MC{1}{c}{}& & & 
$-\frac{1}{2}h_9$   \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

    Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some text! Some 
    text! Some text!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, I can see what you said I am overwriting and, second, how can I assure the table has the same width as the text? @Herbert

Comment: Then use tabularx with X instead of B

Answer (score 2):

with `tabularx`: first column width is set to desired 38 mm (however, to my opinion is better to use column type `l`, the width of rest of the columns are left to `tabularx` to calculate them:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\let\MC\multicolumn
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]


    \begin{table}[!hbt]
    \centering
\caption{Shape functions for quadrilateral elements.}
\label{tab.:2DQuadShapeFunc}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering $}p{38 mm}<{$} |
                        *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}|}}
\MC{1}{c}{} & \MC{5}{c}{Included only if node i is defined} \\
            & i=5               & i=6 & i=7 & i=8 & i=9                 \\
    \hline
h_1=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1-s)
            & -\frac{1}{2}h_5   & & & -\frac{1}{2}h_8 & -\frac{1}{4}h_9 \\
h_2=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1-s)
            & -\frac{1}{2}h_5   & -\frac{1}{2}h_6 & & & -\frac{1}{4}h_9 \\
h_3=\frac{1}{4}(1+r)(1+s)
            & & -\frac{1}{2}h_6 & -\frac{1}{2}h_7 &   & -\frac{1}{4}h_9 \\
h_4=\frac{1}{4}(1-r)(1+s)
            & & & -\frac{1}{2}h_7 & -\frac{1}{2}h_8   & -\frac{1}{4}h_9 \\
    \cline{1-1}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_5=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1-s)$}
            & & & & & -\frac{1}{2}h_9                                   \\
    \cline{1-2}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_6=\frac{1}{2}(1-s^2)(1+r)$}
            & \MC{1}{c}{} & & & & -\frac{1}{2}h_9                       \\
    \cline{1-3}
\MC{1}{l}{$h_7=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2)(1+s)$}
            & \MC{2}{c}{}      & & & -\frac{1}{2}h_9           \\
    \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

for more vertical space in cells is used macro `\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`, removed are your column definitions (since they are not used)

*note:*

- if you use `tabularx` at least of one column had to be `X` type
- since macro `\makegapedcells` is not compatible with `m` column type, the redefinition of `X` columns `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\normalsize}m{#1}}` is deleted.
- definition of new commands if they intended to be used globally (in whole document) should be in preamble (on this way  is more simple to find them), locally is sensible to define them, if they should valid only in the environment, where are defined